# Order a data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.frame

```
> variable_importance
      Overall
x.1  87.30483
x.2  88.59212
x.3  34.16171
x.4  35.72880
x.5  50.62831
x.6  44.76673
x.7  31.12285
x.8  43.04628
x.9  33.01750
x.10 30.72718
```

I would like to order the data frame by the `Overall` variable, but such that the `x.?`
identifiers remain with their respective values.

I.e. it should end up as

```
x.2  88.59212
x.1  87.30483
x.5  50.62831
[...]
```

`order` just gives me the indeces of the rearranged data frame and I loose the row identifiers.

How can I do this and is there a solution using the `data.table` library?

Comment: Minor nitpick: `data.table` is a "package," and the directory where packages are stored is a "library." It's an unfortunate naming convention, but we're stuck with it.

Comment: The solution using the `data.table` package looks like `variable_importance[order(-Overall)]`, as in the answer below. The `drop` thing isn't required. This only works if you load the package and then convert your data.frame to a data.table.

Comment: I just wrote an answer at http://stats.stackexchange.com but in the meantime the question got moved here. So the question was locked and I was not able to post it and I just saw Frank beat me to it.

Answer (score 1):

Use `order` to index into `variable.importance` but also use `drop = FALSE` to avoid coercing the data frame to a vector and losing the row names:

```
> variable.importance[order(-variable.importance),, drop = FALSE]
      Overall
x.2  88.59212
x.1  87.30483
x.5  50.62831
x.6  44.76673
x.8  43.04628
x.4  35.72880
x.3  34.16171
x.9  33.01750
x.7  31.12285
x.10 30.72718
```

Answer (score 0):

An data.table example:

```
require("data.table")
variable_importance <- data.frame(Overall=c(87.30483,88.59212,34.16171,35.72880,50.62831,44.76673,31.12285,43.04628,33.01750,30.72718), row.names=paste0("x.",1:10))
variable_importance # show data.frame
dt <- as.data.table(variable_importance, keep.rownames=T) # new data.table, by value (copy)
#dt <- setDT(variable_importance, keep.rownames=T)  # new data.table, by reference (so variable_importance is now the same data.table, too)
setorder(dt, -Overall)  # order data.table reverse by column Overall
setnames(dt, "rn", "")  # delete colname "rn"
dt # show data.table
```

`setDT` promotes `variable_importance`, which is much faster on huge data sets. 
When you transform the data.frame to a data.table you have to specify `keep.rownames=T` and you get a new column called `rn` with the original `rownames`, as data.table automaticly numbers the rows. 
Normly, when workign with `data.table`, you should not asign empty column names as you work with them. It is better practice to make a new column called `id`.

```
setnames(dt, "", "rn")  # give column back it's name to work with it
dt[,id:=as.integer(substr(rn, start=3, stop=nchar(rn)))]  # extract numbers from rownames
dt[,rn:=NULL] # delete column rn
setcolorder(dt, c("id","Overall"))  # reorder columns
dt # show data.table
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use apply to sort your data by the mentioned column

```
data<- structure(list(V1 = structure(c(1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 
10L, 2L), .Label = c("x.1", "x.10", "x.2", "x.3", "x.4", "x.5", 
"x.6", "x.7", "x.8", "x.9"), class = "factor"), V2 = c(87.30483, 
88.59212, 34.16171, 35.7288, 50.62831, 44.76673, 31.12285, 43.04628, 
33.0175, 30.72718)), .Names = c("V1", "V2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))

apply(data, 2, sort)
```

Answer (score 0):

From [version 1.9.5 of `data.table`](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation) (currently devel), you can also use `setorder()` on a `data.frame`. It reorders the input object by reference.

```
require(data.table)
setorder(df, -Overall)
df
#       Overall
# x.2  88.59212
# x.1  87.30483
# x.5  50.62831
# x.6  44.76673
# x.8  43.04628
# x.4  35.72880
# x.3  34.16171
# x.9  33.01750
# x.7  31.12285
# x.10 30.72718
```

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29331287/559784) for benchmarks on how `setorder()` is both fast and memory efficient.